# Program crashes as it executes `free()`

Tags: c, free, binary-search-tree

I am dealing with a BST and I have to deallocate a node with no children. So my plan has the following steps:

1. reach the node;
2. check it has no children;
3. figure out if the node is a left-child or a right-child;
4. deallocate the node and set the pointer to `NULL`.

My plan miserably fails when the intruction `free(father->left)` is reached. I can't figure out why the program crashes even though I am sure `father->left` contains the memory address of the node I am trying to get rid of. What is going on?

```
 Nodo *destroy_a_node(Nodo *root, Nodo *father, const int value)
    {
        if (root != NULL)
        {
            if ((root->value) > value)
            {
                root->left = destroy_a_node(root->left, root, value);
            }
            else if ((root->value) < value)
            {
                root->right = destroy_a_node(root->right, root, value);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("I am %d and my father is %d\n", root->value, father->value);
                if (has_no_children(root))
                {
                    if (father->left == root)
                    {
                        free(father->left);
                        father->left = NULL;
                    }           
                }
                     // More code to come...
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: The `!= NULL` checks is superfluous clutter, as are the parentheses around `root->value`, because `->` trumps `>`.

Comment: In such cases I cannot suggest too strongly to use `valgrind` (if the platform supports it). It is a *'na mano santa* :-). It might be that `father->left` does not point to memory allocated by `*alloc`, or at that precise address, for example.

Comment: Any reason you don't go the iterative way? It's faster...

Comment: Heap corruption was usually caused somewhere earlier than the code where it actually crashes....

Comment: `return root;`? Isn't it being `free`d?

Comment: @JohnBupit no, I need to get rid of the node and the fuction has to return the addess of the root element.

Comment: @lserni in that case how do I fix it?

Comment: First of all you need to determine what happened. Is `father->left` not `malloc`'ed? Then you need to assign it to the beginning of an allocated memory block (not, let's say, in the middle). Is it some other problem? You need to tell us *what* problem. The number of possible errors is enormous. Even if one listed them all, would you really have the time and patience to read the list and test each entry? You must restrict the field. What platform are you using? Did you try `valgrind` or some equivalent?

Comment: Have you checked if at any point `root->left` or `root->right` is never modified within `has_no_children()`? Be aware that pointer members can be modified even if the parent is passed by value.

Comment: Problem is in 1) `// More code to come...` or the fact it does not exist. 2) remove `else` clause.